# UIDatePicker not scrolling iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scroll, uidatepicker

I do not know what to say but this bug has been haunting me for the last 2 days and I cannot get it to work.

I want to add a UIDatePicker to my view. But for some reason it is not scrolling. I just dragged and dropped the control but without any luck. I checked my view is user-interaction enabled. I even created a dummy view controller which only has a picked in it and made it the initial view controller, still no scrolling happening.

All other interactions are fine.

I created a new project from scratch and simply dropped a picker in its view and tested. It scrolled!!! Not sure why the one in my app is not.

I know you will ask for code, but there is no code here. Jut adding the picker in an initial vc and no action is happening.

Any idea what could be wrong? where i should look?

Cheers

Comment: Are you using `Auto Layout`? Try disabling it and then see.

Comment: Yes I am. I have tried your suggestion but again without any luck :(

Comment: Hard to believe. Its not even scrolling. Why don't you add it programmatically?

Comment: @raurora I know mate. It is driving me really crazy. I tried ur suggestion (not sure why it did not occur to me!) but again nothing :S

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code

```
#import "DatePickerViewController.h"

@interface DatePickerViewController ()

@end

@implementation DatePickerViewController

-(void)getSelection:(id)sender
{
   NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc]
       initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];

   NSDate *pickerDate = [_datePicker date];
   NSString *selectionString = [[NSString alloc] 
       initWithFormat:@"%@",
       [pickerDate descriptionWithLocale:usLocale]];
   _dateLabel.text = selectionString;
}
.
.
.
@end
```

Comment: I am looking for the UIDatePicker ui control, not date only. it is the tumbler UI. Thanks any ways